# Exception while storing lucene index in DB

Tags: lucene, compass-lucene

I’m using lucene version 4.0.0 and compass 2.2.0 to store lucene index in Mysql.

Am getting the following error and am stuck with that.

```
Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.store.IndexInput: method ()V not found
```

And also can you tell me which will perform better.
Storing index in FS or DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucene 4.0 involves significant changes in the API, which Compass undoubtedly does not support.  Development stopped on Compass over two years ago.

The project has effectively been replaced by [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/), as the creator of Compass explains in [this blog post](http://www.kimchy.org/the_future_of_compass/).  You should look into using ElasticSearch instead.

As far as storing the index, store it in the file system.  As far as I can tell, the DB storage feature from Compass hasn't been brought into ElasticSearch.  Frankly, it seems like a bit of a strange feature, and I can only assume it would involve a hit to performance, though I haven't found any resources clearly addressing that.  I would recommend not trying to store an index in your database unless you have a good reason why you really need to.